# Doubling Game Simulation

Tags: c#, algorithm, statistics, simulation, probability

I would like to know if this simulator works as it should because I don't think these are logical answers, but can't capture mistake either.

I have written a simulator for the following game(Given a deck of cards and 1 point) to find most optimal strategy(what is dealers highest card to continue game)

```
 1. Dealer picks a card and shows it to you(Dealer can't pick Joker)
 2. You decide whether to play or no
 3.1. If you don't play you get current points and finish game
 3.2. If you play you pick a Card
 3.2.1. If your card is higher you get double points and go back to step 1
 3.2.2. If your and dealer's cards are equal you go back to step 1
 3.2.3. If dealer's card is higher you lose all points and finish
```

The simulation shows win coefficient for choosing each MAX card to play.It shows these numbers which is highly doubtful to me.I expected it to grow to 1.5 till 7 and then go back to 1.

(First-Win/number of simulations,Second-Max card dealer can get for you to continue game)

```
1 -1
1.0853817 0
1.1872532 1
1.3126581 2
1.4672619 3
1.6704736 4
1.9485809 5
2.2674231 6
2.9993735 7
3.5692085 8
4.3581477 9
4.0109722 10
2.3629856 11
0 12
```

Here's C# code:

```
using System;

namespace Codeforces
{
    class Program
    {
    static int[] k = new int[54];

    static Random rand = new Random();

    static long Doubling(int i, long f)
    {
        int d = rand.Next(52);

        if (k[d] > i) return f;

        int ch = d;
        while (ch == d) ch = rand.Next(54);

        if (k[d] > k[ch]) return 0;

        if (k[d] == k[ch]) return Doubling(i, f);

        return Doubling(i, f * 2);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 54; i++) k[i] = i / 4;

        for (int i = -1; i < 13; i++)
        {
            long sum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < 1e7; j++)
            {
                sum += Doubling(i, 1);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(sum / 1.0e7 + " " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: So whats the question or problem?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add, I'd like to know if this simulator works well

Comment: Do you mean "pick" (where you choose the card) or "draw" (where it is assigned randomly)?

Comment: I mean you taking card randomly, you don't know what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a C# programmer, but it looks like your basic approach is mostly correct.  I would recommend using a loop rather than recursion.

Your problem description is vague regarding the value of jokers and whether dealer discards jokers when drawn or magically just doesn't draw them—you seem to have gone for the latter if I'm reading your code correctly.

It also appears that the way you implemented the recursion implicitly replaces cards in the deck after each play of the game rather than playing through the deck.

When I implemented this independently in another language, I got comparable results.  Looks to me like your intuition is wrong.